# Is anyone having sending email with attachment using Spring integration java DSL configuration

Tags: java, spring-integration-dsl

I am working on project where it only having few modules which expects spring integration concepts . I am trying to send an email with excel sheet as attachment using JAVA DSL SI . I have seen samples and projects in github are done by XML way. Please someone can suggest me the blog or projects or post the code to look up the entire flow and understand.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? There is a DSL example at the bottom of the page.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html

Comment: @Tristan no I have seen that . I could not there the attachment part that's why I asked here .

Comment: answer -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61874126/how-to-add-attachments-in-mail-using-spring-integration-mail-with-dsl-configurat